# Why are these DOS Variables Empty? (e.g. %DATE%, %ERRORLEVEL%)

Tags: batch-file, command-line, dos

I am using Windows XP SP3.

If I open a Command Prompt window, and type

```
ECHO %DATE%
```

I get:

```
14-08-2018
```

like I should.

But If I exit Windows and boot my computer from a bootable USB Flash Drive that has DOS
(real DOS, not the command prompt inside Windows),
and enter the same command,
then `%DATE%` seems to be empty.

The command

```
ECHO %DATE%
```

replies

```
ECHO is On
```

Because it thinks that I just wrote `ECHO`,
since the value returned from `%DATE%` is "".

I tried it with 2 different DOS Versions..
Win98's DOS, and WinME's DOS.
(2 different USB Flash Drives)

Does anyone know why I cannot get the Date in real DOS,
while I can successfully get it when I am in Windows' command prompt?

Comment: Why do you expect `%DATE%` to be populated?

Comment: It's an environment variable.. Fact is that in Windows XP's command prompt it is populated.. so in real DOS it isn't? BTW It just one example.. there are more, like %ERRORLEVEL% and probably more..

Comment: Because MS-DOS and Windows are two different operating systems and MS-DOS's command prompt isn't Windows's command prompt. The later is based on the former but has added numerous features.

Comment: Hmm.. But %ERRORLEVEL% is a variable that existed from DOS days, I remember that from personal use. Why do I get an empty string that means the variable does not exist, instead of getting 0 or any value which is 0-255?

Comment: Pretty sure you never used %errorlevel% in your days of DOS.  You most likely used `IF ERRORLEVEL 1`.

Comment: there are no such environments like `%USERNAME%`, `%USERPROFILE%`, `%WINDIR%`... either. The fact that they exist in Windows doesn't mean DOS must also have them. Those are completely different environments

Comment: I wonder why 2 people downvoted this question. In any case, **Squashman:** I booted now to DOS, and `ECHO ERRORLEVEL` simpy prints "ERRORLEVEL". On the other hand `ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%` prints "ECHO is On". From `ECHO ERRORLEVEL` we can learn that it does not interpret it, it thinks it's just a string to print.. **phuclv:** I know.. I did not expect to have %USERNAME%, %USERPROFILE% etc in DOS.. But %ERRORLEVEL% not exists? Maybe I am not doing it right

Comment: @spaceman: correct: `echo errorlevel` just prints the string `errorlevel`. but `if errorlevel` is a [complete different thing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080926-00/?p=20743)

Comment: Thank you very much Stephan.. I now understand. I will use IF in that case. BTW, isn't there a way to print its value, like for debugging purposes?

Comment: @spaceman use a `@` or no one will be notified. Just run `SET` to get a list of environment variables (or `SET ERR` to get variables begin with ERR) and you'll see

Comment: BTW, there is a solution if one wants to actually know the value of ERRORLEVEL.. The solution is a bit funny, see the first code piece here: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%ERRORLEVEL%` is not a variable in DOS

> ## `%ERRORLEVEL%`
>
> In COMMAND.COM of DR-DOS 7.02 and higher, this pseudo-variable returns the last error level returned by an external program or the `RETURN` command, f.e. "0".."255". See also the identically named pseudo-variable `%ERRORLEVEL%` under Windows and the `IF ERRORLEVEL` conditional command.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#DOS

As you can see, it only exists in DR-DOS 7.02 onwards and Windows. DR-DOS also has `%ERRORLVL%`

OTOH `%DATE%` only exists on Windows

> ## `%DATE%`
>
> This pseudo-variable expands to the current date. The date is displayed according to the current user's date format preferences.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows

They're new features of cmd.exe which requires [command extension](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) to be enabled

> If Command Extensions are disabled, the following dynamic variables will be not accessible:
>
> ```
> %CD% %DATE% %TIME% %RANDOM% %ERRORLEVEL% %CMDEXTVERSION% %CMDCMDLINE% %HIGHESTNUMANODENUMBER%
> ```
>
> https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html

Therefore if you turn off command extension for DOS compatibility you'll also lose those variables on Windows cmd.exe

Comment: Thank you phuclv. Amazing how limiting Batch file programming is, the years that passed made me forgot its limitations. In that case I will simply write what I need in another language, and compile it to a .COM or .EXE. No doubt I will be able to get the Date there, hopefully I will also be able to get the ErrorLevel variable...