# echo %errorlevel% in dos4gw

Tags: batch-file, dos, dosbox

I have a batch script which uses DOS4GW.exe, this is used to run myprogram.exe if this program fails I need to print the error level on the screen.

```
dos4gw myprogram.exe 
echo %errorlevel%
```

above batch script give me output as follows:

```
Echo is on
```

but does not print the error level.

```
dos4gw myprogram.exe
```

if errorlevel 3 goto area1

if errorlevel 2 goto area2

if errorlevel 1 goto exit

goto exit

Comment: You need to be aware that `DOS4GW.EXE` is the command you're running and `MYPROGRAM.EXE` is, in this case, an argument to it. I would expect that any returned errorlevel would be from the execution of `DOS4GW` which will execute first in order to link into `MYPROGRAM.EXE`. Can you update your question to tell us what is output when there is an error, perhaps examples of output from a failing example and that from a working one would help. Can you also explain why you need to print the errorlevel? and what are the errorlevels built into both `MYPROGRAM.EXE`? and `DOS4GW.EXE`?

Comment: yes dos4gw takes argument as myprogram.exe, it produces 3 errors errorlevel 1, 2 and 3, this errorlevel should be displayed on screen.

Comment: So are you telling me there is no error level of `0`? What are those error levels returned for? Are those specifically returned from `DOS4GW` or `MYPROGRAM` Is anything returned at the console when there is an error? Currently unless you're lucky enough to find somebody still using both of these programs together, your question is too broad, _(unless you can furnish us with enough information to replicate and/or fully understand your issue)_.

Comment: myprograrm.exe returns these codes,
`dos4gw myprogram.exe 

if errorlevel 3 goto area1

if errorlevel 2 goto area2

if errorlevel 1 goto exit

goto exit`

Comment: Keep in mind there is a difference between `errorlevel` and `%errorlevel%`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are these DOS Variables Empty? (e.g. %DATE%, %ERRORLEVEL%)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51841636/why-are-these-dos-variables-empty-e-g-date-errorlevel)