# MS-DOS Date Variable in Batch File

Tags: batch-file, dos

I'm trying to write a batch file in MS-DOS and need a way to get the date as a variable for folder names. %date% does not work on MS-DOS, it just returns a blank variable. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: While this isn't off-topic for StackOverflow, you might get better help if you ask the question in [retrocomputing.se] and include the version of MS-DOS you're using (the output of the `VER` command). Note that if you're using CMD under Windows, that's _not_ MS-DOS, and should _not_ be asked in Retrocomputing.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if there was a better place to ask this. It Is MSDOS... In fact I'm having great difficulty finding information for MSDOS and NOT CMD.

Comment: [Why are these DOS Variables Empty? (e.g. %DATE%, %ERRORLEVEL%)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51841636/995714)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, given in Paul Somerson’s *DOS Power Tools*, second edition, uses two batch files. The first one is used as-is; it must be named `CURRENT.BAT`:

```
@echo off
set day=%3
set date=%4
```

The second is created whenever you need the date:

```
echo | more | date > date$.bat
```

Then run `DATE$.BAT`, and you’ll get the current day of the week in `%DAY%`, and the date in `%DATE%`.

`echo | more | date` causes `date` to output the current date and then abort; this produces output of the form

```
Current date is Fri 17/06/2022
Enter new date (dd-mm-yy):
```

(The date format will vary depending on country settings.)

Storing this in a batch file and running it runs `CURRENT.BAT` with the arguments “date”, “is”, “Fri”, and  “17/06/2022”. Because batch files *replace* each other (unless `CALL` is used), the second line in `DATE$.BAT` is not executed and doesn’t cause any errors.

Note that this is MS-DOS specific, and locale specific. It can be adapted to other locales, but it will be more complicated to adapt to DOS clones such as DR DOS.

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved by (mis-)using the prompt command

```
@echo off

%comspec% /C FOR %%n in (1 2) do PROMPT SET _date=$d$_ | find /V "PROMPT" > temp.bat
call temp.bat
del temp.bat

echo currentDate is %_date%
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats a useful trick, I'm new to dos so I'd never have thought of it!

Comment: Since you seem knowledgeable about this, do you know how I would make a substring for this? I tried set %_date2%=%_date:~3,2% to get the month, but when I echo it I get echo is off. In fact when I echo any substring it returns empty... Any ideas before I post another question? I was under the impression this was valid for MSDOS and CMD from what I've found online

Comment: `DOS` `set` has no substring abilities it's only `set var=value`. No /a or /p either. I have bookmarked [a DOS command referernce](https://www.i8086.de/dos-befehle/set.html) (in German - haven't found an English version yet)

Comment: @Stephan [I've compiled the differences here](https://superuser.com/a/1411173/241386)

Comment: @ChrisMcQueen Thanks, yes I wrote a substring MSDOS script. But it's a bit too long for a comment. You should better ask a separate question

Comment: @Stephan The `set` command can't , but a for loop can, see [String manipulation in MS-DOS 6.22 batch files](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/24670/24850)